# MacBook Pro requires SMC reset after every boot when on battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management

Booting my mid2015 15" MacBook Pro (with FileVault2) from battery works as expected – only that it will hibernate immediately after the user has been logged in. Then I have to perform a SMC reset and I can start it again and work normally until the battery is empty. Apart from that I see no other power-related issues and battery life is still good.

[image]

Is SMC maybe somehow broken or is my battery simply approaching its end-of-life?